# Processing HDFS files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Let me begin by saying I am a complete newbie to Hadoop. My requirement is to analyse server log files using Hadoop infrastructure. The first step I took in this direction was to stream the log files and dump them raw into my single node Hadoop cluster using Flume HDFS sink. Now I have a bunch of files with records which look something like this:

timestamp req-id level module-name message

My next step is to parse the files (separate out the fields) and store them back so that they are ready for searching.

What approach should I use for this? Can I do this using Hive? (sorry if the question is naive). The information available on the internet is overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HCatalog or Impala for faster querying.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation you have time series data.Hadoop with HDFS itself is not meant for random access or querying. You can use HBase a database for hadoop as HDFS a backend filesystem. It is good for random access.
Also for your need parsing and rearranging data, you can make use of Hadoop's MapReduce.HBase has built in support for this. HBase can be used for input/output of MapReduce Job.

Basic information you can get from [here](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html). For better understanding try Definitive Guide for HBase / HBase in Action books.